# How to check intersection of subqueries in query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the next query:

```
SELECT c.client_code, a.account_num, m.account_close_date, u.uso, m.product_name
FROM accounts a INNER JOIN Clients c ON c.id = a.client_id INNER JOIN 
    Uso u ON c.uso_id = u.uso_id INNER JOIN Magazine m ON a.account_id = m.account_id
```

and I need to compare product_name with input parameter.

product_name and input parameter @s are comma-delimited strings.
I use next split function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] 
(   
    @s VARCHAR(max),
    @split CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @temptable TABLE (items VARCHAR(MAX))    
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @x XML

    SELECT @x = CONVERT(xml,'<root><s>' + REPLACE(@s,@split,'</s><s>') + '</s></root>');

    INSERT INTO @temptable          
        SELECT [Value] = T.c.value('.','varchar(20)')
        FROM @X.nodes('/root/s') T(c);
RETURN
END;
```

I think that I need to check the intersection of tables, which I will receive after split of product_name  and after split of input parameter. I trid to do this:

```
WHERE (select * from dbo.Split(m.product_name, ';') 
INTERSECT select * from dbo.Split('product1;product2',';')) 
is not null
```

But it does not work quite right. Please, help me.

Comment: is product name stored as a CSV?

Comment: @gbn: no, it is stored as string like 'p1;p2;p3'

Comment: That is a "CSV" in practice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INTERSECT requires the same column output and is used like UNION or EXCEPT: not in the WHERE clause

Just JOIN onto the udf

```
...
INNER JOIN
Magazine m ON a.account_id = m.account_id
INNER JOIN
dbo.Split(@parameter, ';') CSV ON m.productname = CSV.items
```

If you need to split `m.productname`, if you can't fix the design, use CROSS APPLY

```
...
INNER JOIN
Magazine m ON a.account_id = m.account_id
CROSS APPLY
dbo.Split(m.productname, ';') WTF
INNER JOIN
dbo.Split(@parameter, ';') CSV ON WTF.items = CSV.items
```

However, JOIN and INTERSECT give different results if @parameter has duplicated values. Add a DISTINCT to the UDF for example to get around this. Or change the udf JOIN into EXISTS